# SwiftUI - Present Modal via ContextMenu

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm currently trying to present a modal view by pressing a button in the context menu. This works, but the code which should present the modal view is called twice and this is a problem, because I'm calling some networking requests.

Here is my currently demo project (without networking stuff):

This is the view which is called on app start.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isModal: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Text("Main view")
        }.contextMenu {
            Button("Present Detail") { self.isModal = true }.sheet(isPresented: $isModal) {
                DetailView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the simple detail view

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View")
    }
}
```

So if I place a breakpoint at the line where the `DetailView()` is instantiated, I see that this part is called twice. Is there a better solution to present the modal view, without being instantiated multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

Use instead

```
var body: some View {
    Group {
        Text("Main view")
    }.contextMenu {
        Button("Present Detail") { self.isModal = true }
    }.sheet(isPresented: $isModal) {
        DetailView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything in my case, `DetailView()` is also called twice. The breakpoint is called twice. Isn't that the case with you?

Comment: @patrickS, Hmm.. you're right. But as I see `DetailView.init()` is called twice in any way `.sheet` is activated. It does not depend on `.contextMenu`.

Comment: Could you solve that problem? I have the same problem now

Comment: Hmm.. just retested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1 and `DetailView.init` is called only once.